# Can't access a params key in "conn"

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have this in my app:

```
  defp aaabbbcc(conn, params) do
    conn = Plug.Conn.fetch_query_params(conn)

    Logger.info("#{Kernel.inspect(conn[:params]["some_custom_params"])}")
```

Exception:

```
  Plug.Conn does not implement the Access behaviour
```

Wasn't the line `Plug.Conn.fetch_query_params(conn)` supposed to cure that? How to fix it then?

Comment: `conn[:params]` ----> `conn.params`

Comment: @JustMichael what do those differ?

Comment: @JustMichael and why does it become ".params"? params should be a structure

Answer (score 3):

You misunderstood [`fetch_query_params`](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Conn.html#fetch_query_params/2).

Note that

> This function does not fetch parameters from the body. To fetch parameters from the body, use the Plug.Parsers plug.

You should use it like this:

```
conn = Plug.Conn.fetch_query_params(conn)
params = conn.query_params
Logger.info("#{Kernel.inspect(params["some_custom_params"])}")
```

> query_params - the request query params, populated through fetch_query_params/2

PS: `conn[:params]` is the same as `conn.params` in most cases.

Here is the implementation of `fetch_query_params`:

```
  def fetch_query_params(%Conn{query_params: %Unfetched{}} = conn, opts) do
    %{params: params, query_string: query_string} = conn
    Plug.Conn.Utils.validate_utf8!(query_string, InvalidQueryError, "query string")
    length = Keyword.get(opts, :length, 1_000_000)

    if byte_size(query_string) > length do
      raise InvalidQueryError,
            "maximum query string length is #{length}, got a query with #{byte_size(query_string)} bytes"
    end

    query_params = Plug.Conn.Query.decode(query_string)

    case params do
      %Unfetched{} -> %{conn | query_params: query_params, params: query_params}
      %{} -> %{conn | query_params: query_params, params: Map.merge(query_params, params)}
    end
  end



 def decode(query, initial) do
    parts = :binary.split(query, "&", [:global])

    Enum.reduce(Enum.reverse(parts), initial, &decode_www_pair(&1, &2))
  end
```

It just decode the query string, and assign it to the `conn.query_params`.

Comment: why is it `conn.params` and not `conn[:params]` here?

Comment: @Gajiiti `conn` is a map. When map does not have the key, `conn.params` will throw a key not exists error. `conn[:params]` return nil.